# Pandas Profiling Hide Tabs

Tags: python, pandas-profiling

Is there a way to display only specific tabs in the pandas profiling report output?

I am using `pandas_profiling.ProfileReport(data)` but I only need the Overview, Variables and Sample tabs. So is there an option to hide the other tabs e.g. something like `pandas_profiling.ProfileReport(data,correlations=False,missing_values=False)` and only display specific parts of the report?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you should be able to do this. Just turn off all correlations and missing value plots.

```
pandas_profiling.ProfileReport(data, 
                               correlations={'pearson':False,'spearman':False,'kendall':False,'phi_k':False,'cramers':False,'recoded':False},
                               missing_diagrams={'bar':False,'matrix':False,'heatmap':False,'dendrogram':False})
```

The names are based on the config file: 
https://github.com/pandas-profiling/pandas-profiling/blob/master/pandas_profiling/config_default.yaml